# Extract public key from certificate in DER format

Tags: openssl, certificate, extract, public-key, der

I have a .cer certificate file, and need to extract the Public Key. I can only extract to PEM format. **The "outform" parameter does nothing**.

```
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in certificate.cer -outform DER -pubkey -noout > publickey.der
```

Is it possible to extract in DER format?

Comment: My question is not very different from other similar questions... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774574/how-can-i-convert-a-pfx-certificate-file-for-use-with-apache-on-a-linux-server

Comment: I find this question relevant and informative.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solved decoding the base64 PEM file:

```
openssl x509 -in certificate.cer -pubkey -noout | openssl enc -base64 -d > publickey.der
```

Any other idea is welcome.